# Multiple Comparable in a class

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I'd like to know if is possible implementing more Comparables for a single class.
I have first to order my arraylist by a integer field and next in another part of my program i have to order it by another field.
How i can do that? I thought about a custom Comparator but it didn't work.

```
public void OrderbyColours(ArrayList<Horses> scuOrderedByColours,
        ArrayList<Horses> ArrayScud) {
    scuOrderedByColours.addAll(ArrayScud);
    Collections.sort(scuOrderedByColours, new Comparator<Horses>() {
        public int compare(Horses o1, Horses o2) {
            return o1.Position - o2.Position;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `I thought about a custom Comparator but it didn't work.`  Why not?

Comment: As you suspected, custom comparator is the way to go here

Comment: If you are creating comparator for `<Horses>` then arguments of `compare` should also be `Horses`.

Comment: yes sorry that was my fault. In the original code the parameters of the compare are written with <horses> too. That was my fault of not traducing. The problem is that i try to print all elements of AL and they aren't sorted i don't understand why.

Comment: Rotom, do you really mean "traducing" here?  I can't make sense of that in this context.

Comment: (Note, because of integer overflows, it's better to use `Integer.compare` rather then subtraction when implementing `Comparable.compare`. Also it can be confusing to modify an argument - better to create a new `List` and return that. And sticking to coding conventions and avoiding non-private variables are great ideas. )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Comparators are not working(which i'm curious as to how they're not working), or you simply don't want to use one, you could write a wrapper class that has an instance of your original class as data.

ex.

```
public class HorsesWrapper implements Comparable<HorsesWrapper>
{
  private Horses horses;

  public int compareTo(HorsesWrapper other)
  {
    // your sort criteria based on the Horse member.
  }
}
```